# Yarn global install of private module

Tags: react-native, gitlab, rename, yarnpkg

I am trying to install a module globally with yarn.

I typed the following command:

```
yarn global add react-native-rename
```

and then I find it in the yarn global directory, and I am able to call it directly since the directory is included in the path.

But if I try to do the same thing with the same cloned repository hosted on my gitlab:

```
yarn global add git+ssh://git@git.company.info:mobile/react-native-rename.git
```

the installation goes fine but the binary is not present into the folder.

```
yarn global list
```

shows the binaries as installed but I am unable to find it, neither looking for it using *which react-native-rename*.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding this to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`?

```sh
export PATH="$(yarn global bin):$PATH"
```

Yarn Global docs

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global/

FYI: Locations on my mac

- Executable: `/usr/local/bin`
- Location of downloaded code: `~/.config/yarn/global/node_modules`

Could you check these two directories?